# Qt QLCDNumber time_t Timer

Tags: c++, qt, timer

I have a tool button in one .cpp (i.e. ExerciseControl.cpp). When the button is clicked, it will trigger two timers in another .cpp (i.e. StatusBar.cpp).

However, the following codes does not work. The timers do not start when I click the button in ExerciseControl.cpp to trigger startExercise().

```
ExerciseControl.cpp:
ExerciseControl::ExerciseControl(void)
{
    myStatusBar = new StatusBar;
}

void ExerciseControl::startExercise()
{
    myStatusBar ->simulationTimer->start(1000);
    myStatusBar ->elapsedTimer->start(1000);
}


StatusBar.cpp:
StatusBar::StatusBar()
{
    simulationTimer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tickSimulation()));
    elapsedTimer = new QTimer;
    QObject::connect(elapsedTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tickSimulation()));

    createButtons();
};

void StatusBar::createButtons()
{
    ...
}

void StatusBar::tickSimulation()
{
    ...
}
```

However, if I declare the following in my constructor, the timers can start automatically, which is not I wanted.

```
StatusBar::StatusBar()
{
    simulationTimer = new QTimer;
    simulationTimer->start(1000);
    QObject::connect(simulationTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tickSimulation()));
    elapsedTimer = new QTimer;
    elapsedTimer->start(1000);
    QObject::connect(elapsedTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(tickSimulation()));
}
```

I need to trigger the timers through my button in ExerciseControl.cpp.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: are you sure that `startExercise()` is correct called when button is pushed ?

Comment: @Blueman: Yes. It is correctly called. I typed them out here as my codes are on a separate computer. The spacing between is my typo error. In my constructor, I connected the button to the slot. `connect(startButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startExercise()));`

Comment: When you run the program through the debugger, do you have any messages in the output window about failing signals / slots?

Comment: @Merlin069: No failing signals/slots messages. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens. The numbers on the LCDNumbers remains at 0. If I declare `simulationTimer->start(1000);` and `elapsedTimer->start(1000);` in my constructor, it can run automatically. If I declare them in `startExercise()` of my other .cpp file, it does not run.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in startExercise, does it get hit?

Comment: @Wallace If my answer was helpful, please up vote it. If it solved your problem, please click on the checkbox near it. By doing these things you will be helping future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

**On the example below**, `ExerciseControl` is a specialization of `QMainWindow` that does 2 things:

- Display a `QTooButton` inside the window;
- Allocate a `StatusBar` object.

[image]

Clicking the button invokes the **slot** `_timers_must_start()` of the class. This **slot** is responsible to call `start_timers()` from the `StatusBar` object, which in turn starts the timers of that object.

I made each timer call a slot that prints something to the screen when the `timeout()` is triggered.

Enjoy.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "exercise_control.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    ExerciseControl ec;
    ec.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**exercise_control.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include "status_bar.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QToolButton>

class ExerciseControl : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ExerciseControl()
    {
        _button = new QToolButton(this);
        _button->setText("Press Me!");
        QObject::connect(_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(_timers_must_start()));

        _statusbar = new StatusBar;

        // Set the size of the window to the size of the button
        setFixedSize(_button->width() ,_button->height());
    }

private slots:
    /* This slot is called by clicking the button */
    void _timers_must_start()
    {
        qDebug() << "ExerciseControl::_timers_must_start: button clicked! Trying to start timers...";
        _statusbar->start_timers();
    }

private:
    QToolButton* _button;
    StatusBar* _statusbar;
};
```

**status_bar.h**:

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class StatusBar : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    StatusBar()
    {
        _timer1 = new QTimer;
        QObject::connect(_timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(_timer1_task()));

        _timer2 = new QTimer;
        QObject::connect(_timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(_timer2_task()));
    }

    ~StatusBar()
    {
        _timer1->stop();
        delete _timer1;

        _timer2->stop();
        delete _timer2;
    }

    void start_timers()
    {
        if (!_timer1->isActive() && !_timer2->isActive())
        {
            qDebug() << "StatusBar::start_timers: OK!";
            _timer1->start(1000); // 1 second interval
            _timer2->start(5000); // 5 seconds interval
            return;
        }

        qDebug() << "StatusBar::start_timers: timers already started, nothing to be done here!";
    }

private:
    QTimer* _timer1;
    QTimer* _timer2;

private slots:
    /* These slots are called by the timers of this class, hence PRIVATE SLOTS */
    void _timer1_task()
    {
        qDebug() << "StatusBar::_timer1_task: 1 second has elapsed";
    }

    void _timer2_task()
    {
        qDebug() << "StatusBar::_timer2_task: 5 seconds has elapsed";
    }
};
```

**test.pro**:

```
QT += widgets

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    exercise_control.h \
    status_bar.h
```